# About Banach Spaces And Absolute Convergence Of Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

How to prove the following two assertions:

1. If in a normed space $X$, absolute convergence of any series always implies convergence of that series, then $X$ is a Banach space.
2. In a Banach space, absolute convergence of any series always implies convergence of that series.

Comment: A complete proof can be found here: http://planetmath.org/?method=l2h&from=objects&name=ProofOfNecessaryAndSufficientConditionsForANormedVectorSpaceToBeABanachSpace&op=getobj

Comment: So nice of you!

Comment: Seirios' planetmath link is now dead. Emanuele's solutions proves 2.

Comment: Proof of 1 can be found here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Absolutely_Convergent_Series_is_Convergent

Comment: Serios' planetmath working link: https://planetmath.org/proofofnecessaryandsufficientconditionsforanormedvectorspacetobeabanachspace

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Take a Cauchy sequence $x_k$. Then you can find a subsequence $n_k$ such that $|x_{n_{k+1}}-x_{n_k}| < 2^{-k}$. Let $y_k = x_{n_{k+1}}-x_{n_k}$. Then $\sum y_k$ is absolutely convergent and, by hypothesys, it converges. But $\sum_{k=1}^N y_k = x_{n_N} - x_{n_1}$ and hence $x_k$ has a convergent subsequence. But since $x_k$ is Cauchy, the whole sequence is convergent.

Comment: Why can we find a subsequence $n_k$ such that $|x_{n_{k+1}}-x_{n_k}|<2^{-k}$?

Comment: Choose $n_k$ so that $|x_m - x_{n_k}|<2^{-k}$ for all $m>n_k$. This is possible by the definition of Cauchy sequence.

Comment: May I ask why $\sum y_k = lim x_{n_k}$ instead of $\sum y_k = lim x_{n_k} - x_{n_1}$?

Comment: You are right! I have corrected it....