# How to show the convergence in $L^p$ spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $f_{n}\in L^{p}(\Bbb{R})\ (1\le p\le\infty)$. For $0<r<1$, if there exists a positive constant $C$ such that $||f_{n+1}-f_{n}||_{p}<Cr^{n}$, how to show $(f_{n})$ converges in $L^{p}(\Bbb{R})$?

Comment: Isn't specific of $L^p$ spaces: is true in any Banach space.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\Vert{#1}\right\Vert} \newcommand{\nrm}{\norm{\bullet}} \newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$

Recall this theorem:

> Let $(V,\nrm)$ a normed $\R$-vector space. The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $(V,\nrm)$ is a Banach space
> 2. For all $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\norm{f_n}<\infty$, there exists $g\in V$ such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\norm{g-\sum_{k=0}^nf_k}=0$$

Now, in your case
$$f_n=f_0+\sum_{k=1}^n(f_{k}-f_{k-1})$$
And $\norm{f_0}_p+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\norm{f_k-f_{k-1}}_p\le\norm{f_0}_p+C\cdot\sum_{k=1}^\infty r^{k-1}=\norm{f_0}_p+C\frac{1}{1-r}<\infty$

Therefore, since the $(L^p(\R),\nrm_p)$ is a Banach space, there exists $g\in L^p(\R)$ such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\norm{g-f_0-\sum_{k=1}^n(f_k-f_{k-1})}_p=\lim_{n\to\infty}\norm{g-f_n}_p=0$$
$\square$

Comment: Could you tell me the reference?

Comment: @user38448-po [Wikipedia states it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space#Definition). The reference to a complete proof should be [in this math.SE post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298587/about-banach-spaces-and-absolute-convergence-of-series).

Comment: Well, not really a complete poof, because the link the posted is broken. For now, you can also find it on H. L. Royden, *Real Analysis*, 2nd edition, page 116, Proposition 4

Answer (score 4):

We can show that $\{f_n:n\ge1\}$ is a Cauchy sequence. Suppose that $n>m$. We have that
\begin{align*}
\|f_n-f_m\|
&=\|f_n-f_{n-1}+f_{n-1}-f_{n-2}+\ldots+f_{m+1}-f_m\|\\
&\le\|f_n-f_{n-1}\|+\|f_{n-1}-f_{n-2}\|+\ldots+\|f_{m+1}-f_m\|\\
&=\sum_{i=m}^{n-1}\|f_{i+1}-f_i\|\\
&<C\sum_{i=m}^{n-1}r^i.
\end{align*}
Since $0<r<1$, the series $\sum_{i=0}^\infty r^i$ converges and the term $\sum_{i=m}^{n-1}r^{n}$ can be made arbitrarily small by choosing large $m$. Hence, the sequence $\{f_n:n\ge1\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.