# $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_n$ converges if $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|x_n\|$ is bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

> Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in a Banach space $X$.
>   The series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_n$ converges in $X$ if $\sum_{n
>  \in \mathbb{N}} \|x_n\| < \infty$.

Is this statement true?

Since $X$ is a Banach space, if we prove the series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_n$ a Cauchy sequence then it converges. That is, for any $m \ge n > N$, there is $\|\sum_{m \in \mathbb{N}} x_m - \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_n\| = \|\sum_{k = n}^m x_k\| < \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$. But how can this be derived from the boundedness of $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|x_n\|$?

Comment: Write the Cauchy condition for the positive series $\sum \|x_n\|$.

Answer (score 4):

Triangle inequality: that follows from the fact that$$\left\lVert\sum_{k=n}^mx_k\right\rVert\leqslant\sum_{k=n}^m\lVert x_k\rVert.$$

Comment: yes but how to show $\sum_{k = n}^m \|x_k\| < \epsilon$ from $\sum_{k = n}^\infty \|x_k\| < \infty$?

Comment: The sequence $\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\lVert x_k\rVert\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is increasing and bounded. Therefore, it converges. It follows that it is a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 1):

In Banach spaces, absolute convergence implies convergence. Since $s_{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\lVert x_{k}\rVert$ in monotonic and bounded, it converges. Therefore the given series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}x_{n}$ converges:

[About Banach Spaces And Absolute Convergence Of Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298587/about-banach-spaces-and-absolute-convergence-of-series)

Answer (score 0):

Since $X$ is a Banach space, it is complete.
Notice that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} ||u_k|| < \infty$ implies that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is some index $N$ such that $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty} ||u_k|| < \epsilon$.

Let $x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n u_k$.
Then for any $m \ge n \ge N$, we have: $||x_n - x_m|| = ||\sum_{k=1}^n u_k - \sum_{k=1}^m u_k|| = ||\sum_{k=n+1}^m u_k|| \le \sum_{k=n+1}^m ||u_k|| \le \sum_{k=N}^{\infty} ||u_k|| < \epsilon$.
Therefore, this is a Cauchy sequence and since $X$ is complete there exists an $x$ that is the limit of the series.