# if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \|x_k\|$ converges , then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k$ also converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $(x_k)$ be a sequence in a Banach space $X$. if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \|x_k\|$ converges , then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k$ also converges.

$\textbf{My attempt}$

Let $(e_k)$ be the orthonormal basis of $X$. since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \|x_k\|$  converges there exists $ 0< M <\infty$ such that $\|x_k\|<M$, then we can write 
$$|\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k| \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k e_k| \le \|x_k\|\|e_k\| < \infty$$

since the series converges absolutely then it converges in ordinary sense.

Comment: Is this useful? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298587/about-banach-spaces-and-absolute-convergence-of-series

Comment: A Banach space (as opposed to Hilbert space) need not have an orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write $\sum x_n$ before proving that the series converges. So your attempt fails. Prove that $\left\|\sum\limits_{k=n}^{m} x_n\right\| \to 0$ as $n,m \to \infty$ which makes the partial sum sequence a Cauchy sequence. Then use completeness to finish the proof.

Comment: would this work? Choose $N$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^j \|x_k\| \le \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for any $j>N$.  Let $v_n = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k$, then to show that $v_n$ is cauchy we have that , for any $n,m>N$ 
$$\|v_n-v_m\| =\| \sum_{k=1}^n x_k- \sum_{k=1}^m x_k\| \le  \sum_{k=1}^n \|x_k\|+ \sum_{k=1}^m \|x_k\| \le \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$$ 
so the sequence $v_n$ is cauchy and by the completeness of the space it converges.

Comment: @stat No. This doesn't work. There is such $N$ unless all the $x_k$'s are $0$.  Choose $N$ such that $ \sum\limits_{k=N}^{\infty} \|x_k\| <\epsilon$.