# Brezis' exercise 6.15.2: $\|I + \lambda (T-\lambda I)^{-1}\| \le \frac{\|T\|}{|\lambda|- \|T\|}$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, operator-theory, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $(E, |\cdot|)$ be a real Banach space. Let $T \in \mathcal L(E)$, i.e., $T:E \to E$ is a bounded linear operator. Let $I:E \to E$ be the identity map. Let $\rho(T)$ be the resolvent set of $T$. Let $\sigma(T)$ be the spectrum of $T$, i.e., $\sigma(T) := \mathbb R \setminus \rho(T)$.
>
> 1. Let $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ such that $\|T\| < |\lambda|$. Prove that
>    $$
>    \|I + \lambda (T-\lambda I)^{-1}\| \le \frac{\|T\|}{|\lambda|- \|T\|}.
>    $$
> 2. Let $\lambda \in \rho(T)$. Check that $(T-\lambda I)^{-1} T = T (T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ and prove that
>    $$
>    d(\lambda, \sigma(T)) := \inf_{h \in \sigma(T)} |\lambda-h| \ge \frac{1}{\| (T-\lambda I)^{-1} \|}.
>    $$

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you please have a check on it? I'm also happy to see other approaches.

---

1. 

We need a result from the same book, i.e.,

> [Exercise 6.14](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4727597/brezis-exercise-6-14-i-t-is-bijective-and-i-t-1-le-frac11) Assume that $\|T\| < 1$.
>
> 1. Prove that $(I-T)$ is bijective and that
>    $$
>    \|(I-T)^{-1}\| \le \frac{1}{1- \|T\|}.
>    $$
> 2. Let $S_n := I+T+\cdots+T^{n-1}$. Prove that
>    $$
>    \|S_n-(I-T)^{-1}\| \le \frac{\|T\|^n}{1- \|T\|}.
>    $$

Clearly, $\lambda \neq 0$. Let $K:= \frac{T}{\lambda}$. Then $\|K\| < 1$. By *exercise 6.14.2*, we get
$$
\|I-(I-K)^{-1}\| \le \frac{\|K\|}{1- \|K\|}.
$$

The claim then follows.

2.

Let $A := (T-\lambda I)^{-1} T$ and $B:=T (T-\lambda I)^{-1}$. Then $(T-\lambda I) A= T$. Because $(T-\lambda I)$ is bijective, it suffices to prove that $(T-\lambda I) B= T$. First, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
B - \lambda I(T-\lambda I)^{-1} &= T (T-\lambda I)^{-1} - \lambda I (T-\lambda I)^{-1} \\
&= (T-\lambda I) (T-\lambda I)^{-1}= I.
\end{align*}
$$

Then $B= I + \lambda I(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ and thus
$$
\begin{align*}
(T-\lambda I) B &= (T-\lambda I)  + (T-\lambda I) \lambda I(T-\lambda I)^{-1} \\
&= (T-\lambda I) + \lambda I= T.
\end{align*}
$$

By *Proposition 6.7* (in the same book), $\sigma(T)$ is compact and $\sigma(T) \subset [-\|T\|, \|T\|]$. Then $\rho(T)$ is open. Let $r:= \frac{1}{\| (T-\lambda I)^{-1} \|}$. As in the proof of *Proposition 6.7*, $B(\lambda, r) :=\{h \in \mathbb R : |h-\lambda| < r\} \subset \rho(T)$. The claim then follows.